# div aligned with paragraph in html cell

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a table where in every cell, there is a small coloured square next to a text.
However, I want the square and the text to be on the same line, and I cannot do it.

Sadly I'm not a css or html master, I've tried many alignment options I found on this and other sites, but none of them worked.
You can look at a minimal example below to understand what I'm talking about.
Is there any way to do it in css? Thank you

```css
.badge{
  background-color: #000000;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  border-radius: 25%;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <table border="1">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div class="badge"></div> not horizontally aligned text
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of nesting a `<div>` for the badge, you could create a [`::before`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before) pseudo element for each `<td>` and make it `inline-block` so the pseudo element stays inline with the text content. This way you can ensure each table data element will have the small colored square before the cells text content.

```css
.badge::before {
  content: "";
  background-color: #000000;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  border-radius: 25%;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

/* Optionally, give the cells different colors */
.badge.two::before {
  background-color: #ae7;
}

.badge.three::before {
  background-color: #f06;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <table border="1">
      <tr>
        <td class="badge one">
          some text in cell 1
        </td>
         <td class="badge two">
          some text in cell 2
        </td>
         <td class="badge three">
          some text in cell 3
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

If you instead want to keep the same HTML structure, you could make the `<td>` a [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox) with `display: flex` to ensure the content is aligned in a row format (side-by-side). Using `align-items` will define how items are aligned along the [cross axis](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Cross_Axis).

```css
.badge{
  background-color: #000000;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  border-radius: 25%;
}

td {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <table border="1">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div class="badge"></div> not horizontally aligned text
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use flexbox:

```css
.badge {
  background-color: #000000;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  border-radius: 25%;
  margin-right: 1em;
}

td {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <table border="1">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="badge"></div>horizontally aligned text
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```